# VS .NET project add icon (the default icon build-action property is content, so how by default to force resource ?)

Tags: visual-studio, icons, resources

in our recent development, an icon was added to the project VS2022 and all was fine until the app was installed using installer. Then we realized that in the case of the installer, the build action should be a resource and not content, so the fix was easy and immediate we just were embarrassed nothing special :) but now we are trying to understand how to avoid the issue next time a new teammate would like to add a new icon, of course, we could adjust our release process with more manual/auto tests, etc. I just being naive enough thought maybe there was an easy way to change the default through VS.NET project config or some kind of configuration. Obviously, I tried Google, but nothing came fruitful all was in vain. Any thoughts?